# What does ">>=" mean in Linux kernel source code?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

in Linux kernel source code, I find below code:

```
    h++;
    pending >>= 1;
```

It is part of `__do_softirq(void)`. But what does ">>=" mean? Why isn't it ">>" as I remember?
Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It simply does

```
pending = pending >>1;
```

In short it divides by 2 an unsigned int.

That's the same construct than `+=`, `/=`, etc.

It's not just `pending >>1` as you remember because that wouldn't store the result of the shift operation in the variable.

Comment: It divides by 2 an _unsigned_ int. C does not specify what happens to a signed int. You're better off using /= in that case.

Comment: yes. precision added. I don't think this construct for dividing by two is really useful today as all compilers probably optimize the `/=2` on unsigned int. You should probably use it mainly when you use the int to store bits.

Comment: @DougCurrie you mean for a *negative* signed integer.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explaination of the "="! I leanrt it.

Answer (score 2):

It's equivalent to

```
pending = pending >> 1;
```

Which bitshifts right the bits in `pending`. This would have the effect of dividing an unsigned int by 2. >> and << are the bitshift operators, and the combination with = behaves the same way += and /= do.