# &= and |= in Java

Tags: java, operators

In a project, I see the following code:

```
//f is a File
boolean acceptable = true;
acceptable &= sweepFilename != null;
acceptable &= f.getName().equals(sweepFilename.toString()); // parsable
acceptable &= id == null || id.equals(sweepFilename.getId());
acceptable &= length == null || length.equals(sweepFilename.getLength());
acceptable &= f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(SweepFilename.EXTENSION);
acceptable |= f.isDirectory();
return acceptable;
```

Can someone explain me what the `&=` and `|=` means?

I understand it as, if acceptable is true then also check the right side and assign the value of the operation (false/true) to acceptable, so that if it is false, then it will not need to check the right side.

Comment: `x &= y;` = `x = x & y;`

Comment: And `&` in turn is the _bitwise_ AND operator.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just like

```
a += b;
```

means

```
a = a+b;
```

, you have

```
a &= b;
```

meaning

```
a = a&b;
```

And of course the same for `|=`.

You have the same construct for other operators in most languages whose syntax inherits from the C language. Look for example at this : [What does ">>=" mean in Linux kernel source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246466/what-does-mean-in-linux-kernel-source-code/11246498#11246498)

See also [the complete list of assignment operators in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Answer (score 3):

`+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `&=`, `|=` and other such operators are in most languages simply shorthands for `a = a + b` and equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

'&' and '|' are bitwise operators. When used with '=' operator, these are just shortcuts for saying:

a&=b the same as a=a&b

Now, what does the a&b returns? It returns the logical 'AND', so it compares bits.
As for boolean values (which are just named constants in Java), they represent 0 and 1 bit (for 'false' and 'true', respectively)

But you can use them with other integer types as well (short, int, long).

```
boolean a = true;
boolean b = false;
a &= b; // it acts like && and || for boolean values
System.out.println(a); //false

int i = 2;
int j = 3;        
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(j));

System.out.println(i&=j); // prints binary '10' == 2 decimal
System.out.println(i|=j); // prints binary '11' == 3 decimal
```

Answer (score 0):

As & is not a short cut operator, it might not be as efficient as using &&. If you did it might look like this.

```
return (sweepFilename != null 
        && f.getName().equals(sweepFilename.toString())
        && (id == null || id.equals(sweepFilename.getId()))
        && (length == null || length.equals(sweepFilename.getLength()))
        && (f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(SweepFilename.EXTENSION))) 
        ||  f.isDirectory();
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `x &= y` is equivalent to `x = x & y`

and

The syntax `x |= y` is equivalent to `x = x | y`